# how to replace one element of array in jsonnet with mixin way?

Tags: jsonnet, ksonnet

we have array imported from libsonnet

```
{
  "volumes": [
    {
      "emptyDir": {},
      "name": "grafana-storage"
    },
    {
      "configMap": {
        "name": "grafana-dashboard-apiserver"
      },
      "name": " grafana-dashboard-apiserver"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to replace this element:

```
    {
      "emptyDir": {},
      "name": "grafana-storage"
    },
```

with this one (same `name`):

```
    {
      "name": "grafana-storage",
      "persistentVolumeClaim": {
        "claimName": "product-nfs"
      }
```

outputs expected :

```
{
  "volumes": [
    {
      "configMap": {
        "name": "grafana-dashboard-apiserver"
      },
      "name": " grafana-dashboard-apiserver"
    },
    {
      "name": "grafana-storage",
      "persistentVolumeClaim": {
        "claimName": "product-nfs"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

"appending" is easy, but how to remove the existing one

example:

```
local x = {volumes: [
  {emptyDir: {}, name: 'grafana-storage' },
  {configMap: {name:  'grafana-dashboard-apiserver'
}, name: ' grafana-dashboard-apiserver'},]};

x 
+ {volumes+: [{name: 'grafana-storage',persistentVolumeClaim: {claimName:'product-nfs'}}]}
```

thanks in advance~

Comment: Shameless plug: you can try using this library: https://github.com/sbarzowski/jsonnet-modifiers. I wrote it with use cases like this in mind.

Comment: cool, nice thought~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to deriving/overloading, `jsonnet` is much easier to work with maps (aka "objects", "dicts", "hashes"), the strategy would be: 1) convert to map, 2) override, 3) convert back to array.

Below snippet implements it:

```
local main_obj = {
  volumes: [
    {
      emptyDir: {},
      name: "grafana-storage",
    },
    {
      configMap: {
        name: "grafana-dashboard-apiserver",
      },
      name: "grafana-dashboard-apiserver",
    },
  ],
};

local obj_overrides = {
  volumes: [
    {
      name: "grafana-storage",
      persistentVolumeClaim: { claimName: "product-nfs" },
    },
  ],
};

// Convert to map for easier overloading, assumes all array elements are maps having "name" field
local toNamedMap(array) = { [x.name]: x for x in array };

// Convert back to array
local toNamedArray(map) = [{ name: x } + map[x] for x in std.objectFields(map)];

toNamedArray(toNamedMap(main_obj.volumes) + toNamedMap(obj_overrides.volumes))
```

Comment: I wrote a libsonet in this way, and it works like charm!, really appreciate it!